# Better way to write a reptitive function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that looks like this:

```
$('.item-one').mouseover(function() {
    $('.img-one').addClass('fit-img');
});

$('.item-two').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.img-two').addClass('fit-img');
});

$('.item-three').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.img-three').addClass('fit-img');
});
```

Is there a better way to write something like the above even though it works?

Comment: don't for loops work for these things?

Comment: Can you show the HTML of Item-one/two/three and Img-one/two/three ?

Comment: You have a mixture of `mouseover` and `mouseenter` - is that intentional?

Comment: You could add a common class for all transitions and then add/remove the class based on the common class instead of item-one - item -two item-three...

Comment: How many elements might come in your HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a mix of common classes to group elements and `data` attributes to store meta data with the element. Try this:

```js
$('.item').mouseover(function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $(target).addClass('fit-img');
});
```

```css
.img {
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.img.fit-img { display: block; }

.img-one { background-color: red; }
.img-two { background-color: green; }
.img-three { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="item" data-target=".img-one">one</a>
<a href="#" class="item" data-target=".img-two">two</a>
<a href="#" class="item" data-target=".img-three">three</a>

<div class="img img-one"></div>
<div class="img img-two"></div>
<div class="img img-three"></div>
```